# Incorrect Syntax near '.' (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

```
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerInsuranceNumber]
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_myConstraint PRIMARY KEY ([dbo].[CustomerStateProvince].[CustomerHQStateProvinceAbbreviation], [CustomerInsuranceNumber])
GO
```

I am trying to create a composite key made up of a column from the table above and a column from another table. 
I get an incorrect syntax near '.' for the periods in `[dbo].[CustomerStateProvince].[CustomerHQStateProvinceAbbreviation]`

How do I fix this error?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't. A primary key must consist of columns within a single table.

Comment: Just how would you expect a PK across tables to work? And [dbo] is in the wrong slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a composite primary key from columns on another table. You need to have that value present on your table. Create a column named `[CustomerHQStateProvinceAbbreviation]`on your `[CustomerInsuranceNumber]` table and make the key as this:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_myConstraint PRIMARY KEY ([CustomerHQStateProvinceAbbreviation], [CustomerInsuranceNumber])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a column from another tablo to primary key. You cannot do this.